# Trying to add global security groups to a folder

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory-group

I wrote a script to create a  new folder based on some company variables and later on add a group with users to handle the permissions on this folder.
I can not find a decent way to add one, or more, AD groups to a folder in the same script.

Here is my script:

```
$parentfolder = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the name of the parent folder (i.e. FOLDER1234)"
$folder = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the name of the new network folder"

New-Item \\DC02\product\$parentfolder\$folder -type directory
Write-Host "Folder has been created!"
Start-Sleep -s 2

$newgroup = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the new group name for this folder (1234-1234-12xx format)"
$description = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the abbreviation of the product (i.e. PDPROD)"
NEW-ADGroup -Name $newgroup -GroupScope Global -Description $description -Path "OU=Project Groups,DC=ourdomain,DC=nl"

do {
    $stringquit = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the member username's to add or press Q if you are done."
    $userfilter3 = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $stringquit}
    if ($userfilter3 -eq $Null,"Q") {
        Write-Host = "User does not exist in AD, please try again"
        Start-Sleep -s 1
    } else {
        if ($stringquit -ne "Q") {
            Write-Output -InputObject $stringquit | Out-File -Append  c:\userlist.csv
        } else {
            Write-Host "You pressed Q, moving on."
        }
    }
} until ($stringquit -eq "Q")

$addgroup = "cn=$newgroup,ou=Project Groups,dc=ourdomain,dc=nl"
$list = Get-Content c:\userlist.csv
foreach ($user in $list) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $addgroup -Member $user
}

#set permissions
$acl = Get-Acl \\DC02\product\$parentfolder\$folder
$ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("1234-all","Modify"."ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($ar)
Set-Acl \\DC02\product\$parentfolder\$folder $acl
```

Comment: @Ansgar: there is some contention as to whether tags should be removed from titles - certainly taggy titles in the form `x | y | question` should be ironed out, but removing keywords like "Powershell" loses important context in the Hot Questions or Related sidebars, where tags are not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace [`SetAccessRule()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sacxhfka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`AddAccessRule()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d49cww7f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The set permissions part in the end is the problem indeed, the rest seems to work. However, the first error shows up when "line2" is running from the last part.

Comment: PS C:\ps> New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("6001-all","Modify"."ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FileSystemAccessRule" and the argument count: "4".
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("6001-all","Modify ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: You have a typo in that statement. Replace the dot between `"Modify"` and `"ContainerIn‌​herit,ObjectInherit"` with a comma.